# Bank System not working

Tags: c++

For some reason my bank script isn't working. More specifically, the `search()` does not work. I kind of understand why it doesn't, probably because of `if(obj.returnId() == n)`, but I have no clue how to fix it. When I search an account, it will only allow me to find the last account made, not any of the previous ones. Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
bool loop = true;

class account
{
          int id;
         char name[40];
         char password[40];
public:
          void getData()
          {
                     cout << "\nEnter your name: ";
                     cin >> name;
                     cout << "\nEnter ID: ";
                     cin >> id;
                     cout << "\Enter pass: ";
                     cin >> password;
          }
          void showData()
          {
                     cout << "\nName: ";
                     puts(name);
                     cout << "\nID: " << id;
                     cout << "\n";
          }
          int returnId()
          {
              return id;
          }
};

void createAccount()
{
    account obj;
    ofstream fileCreate;
    fileCreate.open("accounts.dat", ios::binary|ios::app);
    obj.getData();
    fileCreate.write((char*)&obj,sizeof(obj));
    fileCreate.close();
}

void display()
{
    account obj;
    ifstream fileRead;
    fileRead.open("accounts.dat", ios::binary);
    while(fileRead.read((char*)&obj, sizeof(obj)))
    {
        obj.showData();
    }
    fileRead.close();
}

void search(int n)
{
    account obj;
    ifstream fileRead;
    fileRead.open("accounts.dat", ios::binary);
    while(fileRead.read((char *) &obj, sizeof(obj)) );
    {
        fileRead.seekg(0,ios::beg);
        if(obj.returnId() == n)
        {
            obj.showData();
        }
        else {
            cout << "\nUser not foud!\n";
        }
    }
    fileRead.close();
}








void main()
{
    cout << "Welcome to the Bank.\n\n";

    while (loop==true)
    {
        char choice[10];
        cout << "Please select an option:\n";
        cout << "------------------------------------------------\n";
        cout << "(a)Log into an account\n(b)Create an account\n(s)Search an account\n(e)Exit\n";
        cout << "------------------------------------------------\n";
        cout << "Choice: ";
        cin >> choice;
        choice[0] = tolower(choice[0]);
        cout << "\n------------------------------------------------\n\n";

        switch (choice[0])
        {
        case 'a':
            display();
            break;
        case 's':
            int n;
            cout << "Enter the ID of the account: ";
            cin >> n;
            search(n);
            break;
        case 'b':
            createAccount();
            break;
        case 'e':
            loop = false;
            break;
        default:
            system("CLS");
            cout << "The option \"" << choice[0] <<  "\" is invalid.\n\n\n\n";
            break;
        }

    };
    cout << "\n\n\n";
    cout << "Click anything to exit.";
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Saving a class like that is very fragile, and it may not properly read-back in due to function pointers and vTables. Use a proper serialization library instead.

Comment: Also, is `n` a character? if so: try this: `if(obj.returnId() == 'n')`

Comment: You could have removed a lot of code from this example and still produced the error. Next time, please try to post a minimal example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the semicolon at the end of this line:

```
while(fileRead.read((char *) &obj, sizeof(obj)) );
```

That makes this loop have an empty body.  So you basically read the whole file and throw away the results, except for the last entry.

get rid of this also:

```
fileRead.seekg(0,ios::beg);
```

I don't know why you need that, it would only make you read the first entry over and over.

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe I put the semicolon at the end of a while(). I appreciate everyone's help :)

Answer (score 1):

The other error is that you should only say 'User not found' when you've tested all the accounts and they all failed. Your loop (when you've removed the semi-colon) is saying 'User not found' after every failed test.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't find the entry you are looking for because each time you have read an entry from the file, you reset the position to the beginning. This means that your loop will run forever, reading the same entry over and over again and never finding the entry you search for.

Comment: Except there's a semi-colon which means the seekg isn't in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

the seek might be the problem:

```
while(fileRead.read((char *) &obj, sizeof(obj)) ) //;
{
    // seek to start?
    //fileRead.seekg(0,ios::beg);
    ...
}
```

have a look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

aside, use

```
cout << "text" << endl;
```

for platform-agnostic newlines.

Comment: '\n' is a platform agnostic newline by itself. endl is a '\n' plus a flush operation.